# identify Itunes connect users with apple developer acoount users

Tags: app-store-connect

I am using apple developer account to distribute app through device UDID. Now i want to use itunes connect. Is there any way to match the itunes connect user's UDID to match with the apple developer user's UDID so that already existing user on apple developer account can use the application without paying more and with full features?

Comment: Testers using TestFlight don't need to pay anything and they don't need an account on iTunes Connect.

Comment: This is neither an iOS, nor an Objective-C, related question.

Comment: You can distribute promo codes to your test users so they can download the released app for free

Comment: There is a very good chance, that any solution that actually managed to achieve what you are trying to do, would violate Apple's Terms of Service relative to using UDID and other such forms of "Tracking".